# BJT switch: Exact base resistor to limit current, or allow more current than needed & then use a current limiting resistor?

Tags: power, switches, bjt

Is it better to adjust the base resistor of a BJT switch to get the exact current you want for an LED or other component in the main circuit? Or is it better to have the BJT switch allow more current than needed in the main circuit and then use a current limiting resistor there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a current limiting resistor. Beta is highly variable, so you can't really rely on it for setting collector current.

Usually when you switch an LED, it is a saturated switching application. So you assume Vce will be around 0.2V (or use Vce(sat) from datasheet). Pick a current limiting resistor for the LED based on the typical Vf of the LED. And use a design beta of 10 or 20 to calculate the base resistor value for the BJT.

You can also use a small signal MOSFET such as a BSS138. Then you don't need to worry about base current.